# Understand implementation of exponential moving average (in case of unix load average)

Tags: algorithms, code-reviews, math, implementations

The UNIX load average gives 3 numbers over 1/5/15 minute time intervals. It's supposed to be an indicator of how busy a UNIX machine is. The global load average is an exponentially decaying average of number of runnable/uninteruptable tasks.

I'm interested to implement such kind of exponential decay algorithm in my project for a slightly different purpose, but also to take averages. So I did some research how exactly this load average is computed in UNIX.

Nowadays the [implementation is quite involved](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16b3d0cf5bad844daaf436ad2e9061de0fe36e5c/kernel/sched/loadavg.c) for various reasons. Since I'm mostly interested in the exponential decay part when computing the average, I found a simpler description of the original implementation:

```
#define FSHIFT    11          /* nr of bits of precision */ 
#define FIXED_1   (1<<FSHIFT) /* 1.0 as fixed-point */ 
#define LOAD_FREQ (5*HZ)      /* 5 sec intervals */ 
#define EXP_1     1884        /* 1/exp(5sec/1min) fixed-pt */ 
#define EXP_5     2014        /* 1/exp(5sec/5min) */ 
#define EXP_15    2037        /* 1/exp(5sec/15min) */ 

#define CALC_LOAD(load,exp,n) \
 load *= exp; \
 load += n*(FIXED_1-exp); \
 load >>= FSHIFT;
```

From http://perfdynamics.blogspot.com/2014/06/load-average-in-freebsd.html, where they say:

> The CALC_LOAD macro is updated (internally) every 5 seconds and the m-index in eqn.(1) refers to the weight associated with each of the 1, 5, or 15 minute averaging windows.

What I don't understand: If there is a loop, which on each iteration gets `n`, the number of tasks, every 5 seconds, then how do the exponential decay constants here help to take the load average of 1 minute, 5 minutes or 15 minutes?

A simple example that could be calculated with pen & paper would be really useful.

What I'm particularly confused is, to me it seems we just add onto a single variable over and over again, every 5 seconds. Now, how does this then give the avg. over 1 minute, 5 minutes, 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, these functions are a bit opaque because they are implemented without floating point operations, as access to FPU within the kernel isn't guaranteed on a number of platforms. If you re-formulate them in floating point, they might get a little clearer. The formulas in comments give some hints.

EXP_1 expressed as a float would be 0.919921875 (1884/2048). This is reasonably close to (1/e)^(1/12) ~= 0.920044414629323. When using this factor in an exponential decay, the value at t=0 is multiplied with this factor at each step, resulting in the original value divided by e after 12 steps (1 minute). By adding the current load value multiplied by 1-(1/e)^(1/12) the floating average is updated to asymptotically approach the load.

Similarly, EXP_5 is 0.9833984375, close to (1/e)^(1/60) ~= 0.983471453821618, and EXP_15 is 0.99462890625, close to (1/e)^(1/180) ~= 0.994459848004897.

To see the effect of EXP_1 with a pocket or desktop calculator, you can start with 1, multiply with 1884/2048 12 times, and compare the result 0.367291902549175 to 1/e ~= 0.367879441171442.

The macro CALC_LOAD is executed for each load average value, so it is not a single variable but 3 variables that get updated.

Hope this helps understanding the process. Fixed point is fun when it works but can be daunting to understand.

Comment: Hey Hans-Martin, that's super helpful, thanks. So the idea is, assuming we start with a count of tasks of n=1, and assuming no more tasks are active, then the evaluation of the above loop  every 5 seconds models the exponential decay over 1 minute/5 minutes/15 minutes.

Comment: @Max exactly. Actually the start value is arbitrary, setting it to 1 and updating with 0 just helps to see that the decay amounts to 1/e per 1/5/15 minutes.